# Encoding PHP array fetched from MySQL into JSON unicode escaped using PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

I am using a PHP 5.2.17 server + MySQL 5.1.65.

I have a table containing a field that is `VARCHAR utf8_general_ci` and I fetch a record from this table.

This is how I open the connection, nothing special:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
```

I need to respond with a JSON object that contain special characters Unicode escaped, I mean the `\u00e1` notation.

```
 $result = mysql_query(sprintf("select * from data t where t.domain='%s'", escape($domain));


  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $r[] = array(
      "tagid" => $row['DATAID'],
      "name" => $row['NAME']
    );
   )

$encoded = json_encode($r);
header('Content-type: application/json');
exit($encoded);
```

My problem is fields containing special characters (áé..) are returned as `null` in the JSON response.

After having Googled for a while I see that PHP 5.2 lack the `json_encode` parameters, so I need to unicode-escape name fields manually. But how could I do this?

Comment: any reason you can't upgrade your PHP 5.2? Seeing as it was declared end-of-life nearly *two years* ago already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode()` should be able to handle UTF-8 data perfectly well - JSON is UTF-8 only, so it would be strange for PHP to not have this particular function as UTF-8 aware.

```
$array = array('key' => 'せ');

var_dump(json_encode($array)); // string(16) "{"key":"\u305b"}"
```

Your column *collation* might be `VARCHAR utf8_general_ci` but that does not mean the characters are *encoded* as UTF-8. Your table should be created with:

```
CREATE TABLE ... CHARACTER SET utf8
```

And you should probably execute this as your first query:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Comment: Thanks, all I was missing is the `SET NAMES utf8` as a first query.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `json_encode` yourself, which should not be problematic, or check others' code, like [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#89908) (with optional tweaks when you find that necessary).

Answer (score 1):

There's actually no need to do this escaping. What's much more likely, is that your input data is not actually valid UTF-8.

Changing the collation of a table may not fix this. Are you absolutely certain it's valid?

Also: stop using mysql_ functions and use PDO or mysqli. The mysql_ functions have been deprecated a long, long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You might also find that base64_encode(ing) the data will make json_encode more reliable.  In your example:
"tag

```
"tagid" => base64_encode($row['DATAID'])
...
```

Then you json_encode the whole thing.  Of course you have to base64_decode at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

If you (like me) are stuck with a pre 5.4 `PHP` environment, this works for latin accented multirow `return`s fetched using either `mysql` or `mysqli` (string originally `MySQL utf8`):

```
$encoded = jsonEncode($r);
exit($encoded);
function jsonEncode($outputArray) {
    $outputMe = "[";
    $k = 0;
    foreach ($outputArray as $key => $valueArray) {
        if ($k) { 
            $outputMe.=","; 
        }
        $outputMe.="{";
        $l=0;
        foreach ($valueArray as $position => $value) {
            if ($l) { 
                $outputMe.=","; 
            }
            $outputMe .= '"'.$position.'":"'.$value.'"';
            $l++;
        }
        $outputMe .= "}";
        $k++;
    }
    $outputMe .= "]";
    return $outputMe;
}
```